# Checking if pairs are equal

Tags: java, equals

This is supposed to be a very simple program, however whenever I try to compile it, I get an error saying that the `otherObject.fst` and `otherObject.snd` variable cannot be found, so my equals method is not working properly. Everything else is working fine. I believe its an issue with my `setFst` and `setSnd` methods. I've tried a bunch of variations, but I can't seem to phrase it correctly. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> implements PairInterface<T1, T2>
{
    // TO DO: Instance Variables
    public T1 first;
    public T2 second;
    public T1 fst;
    public T2 snd;

    public Pair(T1 aFirst, T2 aSecond)
    {
        first = aFirst;
        second = aSecond;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first element of this pair.
     * @return the first element of this pair.
     */
    public T1 fst()
    {
        return this.first;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the second element of this pair.
     * @return the second element of this pair.
     */
    public T2 snd()
    {
        return this.second;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the first element to aFirst.
     * @param aFirst  the new first element
     */
    public void setFst(T1 aFirst)
    {
        // TO DO
        aFirst = fst;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the second element to aSecond.
     * @param aSecond  the new second element
     */
    public void setSnd(T2 aSecond)
    {
        // TO DO
        aSecond = snd;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two pairs are equal. Note that the pair
     * (a,b) is equal to the pair (x,y) if and only if a is
     * equal to x and b is equal to y.
     * @return true if this pair is equal to aPair. Otherwise
     * return false.
     */
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        if (otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (otherObject.fst.equals(this.fst) && otherObject.snd.equals(this.snd))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        // TO DO
    }

    /**
     * Generates a string representing this pair. Note that
     * the String representing the pair (x,y) is "(x,y)". There
     * is no whitespace unless x or y or both contain whitespace
     * themselves.
     * @return a string representing this pair.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        // TO DO
        return "("+first.toString()+","+second.toString()+")";
    }
}
```

Comment: i've never heard of `Object` having an `fst` member ;). I'm pretty sure you are looking to cast, and use `fst()` and `snd()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

otherObject is declared as just an Object type, so it doesn't have any of the attributes of whatever class you created.  It should be the same type as the object you are trying to compare it with.

Comment: That did the trick, can't believe I missed that I've been scratching my heads for hours. Thank you!